# INSERT INTO, return number of rows inserted

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get numbers of rows inserted into a table by a INSERT INTO statement? Preferably by using something like RETURNING in the SQL statement. Alternatively, by using PLPGSQL?

Comment: Closed as dup. If you still prefer to use `returning`, simply `count()` the affected rows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I try the following syntax INSERT INTO ... RETURNING COUNT(*)  I get the following error: aggregate functions are not allowed in RETURNING

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can work around that using a CTE: `with rows as (insert ... returning ...) select count(*) from rows`. The better approach, though, is to get the diagnostics directly, as suggested in the answers from the other post.